# Company not paying my last paycheck, what do I do?

Tags: united-states, termination, compensation

I was recently let go from my job. Their HR advised they would like both parties to leave on good terms. However, I have not received my last paycheck that was legally supposed to be provided to me in their last pay period (the 15th of March) and I have contacted the company's HR numerous times but have not received any response.

I feel at this point, I am getting ignored. In my state, they were supposed to provide me my last pay at the next immediate pay period (the 15th). I am at the point where I'm ready to contact the state's Attorney General and lodge a complaint.

But before I do that, I am tempted to contacting the company's owner and letting him know what is going on. Is this advisable? I really don't know what to do other than that and contact the Attorney General.

Comment: Are you able to go there in person and talk to anyone, you might be able to get more of a response than leaving messages?

Comment: Their HQ is in a different state than where I live.

Comment: Related: [How do I deal with an employer withholding my paycheck?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/23363/how-do-i-deal-with-an-employer-withholding-my-paycheck) and [My former employer is witholding my final paycheck and W2](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/40578/my-former-employer-is-witholding-my-final-paycheck-and-w2)

Comment: Last day was the 8th

Comment: Interesting. In my state, as I understand it, if you are walked out (fired) they pay you immediately without waiting for the next payday. Department of Labor is your next stop.

Comment: Yes, i looked up the labor laws in my state. They say immediately - but they are referring to the next pay period.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go up the ladder.   Have you talked to the head of HR?   Or the senior leadership that HR reports to?  That would be my next step. It's not out of line to contact the owner if it's a small company and he's accessible.  I'd pursue every avenue I could before the legal route.

Answer (score 2):

Get ready to contact the state.

They missed the deadline, and they haven't responded to your calls/emails.

Leave a message in the morning and an email, and tell them if they don't respond before tomorrow you will be contacting the state.

Document the times you contacted them, and who the phone calls and emails were to.

The initial contact from the state should get things moving.